# Which Power Management implementation to use and the differences therein

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter

Upon using an 'RF to DC converter', DC power management is needed. There is a dilemma in the approach as there are a number available.

From the storage capacitor, there is the 'Switched-mode power supply' or more specifically a 'boost converter' that would output the configured power.

Alternatively, there is a 'DC-DC charge pump' connected to a voltage regulator.

The question is the difference between the two approaches and the pros-cons of each. It is my understanding that their function is the same, however I am under the suspicion that there may be naming/wording confusion that I may not be picking up on.

How are boost converters and charge pumps different, and where does the voltage regulator come in?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A charge pump uses capacitors to do the boosting of the input from the lower to the higher voltage. They usually provide an unregulated output voltage which is the double of the input voltage. This means, that for most applications you need a voltage regulator behind the charge pump to get a well regulated voltage.

A pro for the charge pump is its simplicity, as only two capacitors are needed. This turns into another benefit, as they are quite cheap. A con is that their efficiency tends to be low for higher currents.

The boost converter is using an inductor as boosting element. Boost converters are very flexible in their design, and can range from very few milliampere to several ampere. Their quiescent current tends to limit their use in very low power applications as their efficiency drops off at the low end of loads. There are ongoing efforts by manufacturers to reduce this problem, and efficiency was greatly improved in the low power range over the last years.

Boost converters provide a regulated output voltage which might be good enough for some applications, but the voltage ripple might be to much for sensitive circuits, so a linear regulator might still be used to reduce the noise. For a purely digital circuit using no linear converter should be fine.

Because they need an inductor, boost converters are more expensive and take up more board space than a simple charge pump.

Without knowing more about the requirements, its hard to suggest the right solution, though "RF to DC" sounds like energy harvesting and probably low power levels, so a charge pump might be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the part that stores energy during conversion. A boost converter uses an inductor, while a charge pump uses a capacitor.

A charge pump is more common for very low power requirements in the ballpark of mA, and voltage doubling/tripling. Within this limitations, it is often preferred over boost converts due to simplicity.